# Why is my 2D Array code working with malloc(0)?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have weird problem: my code is working. Specifically this is working. Why?

```
char **array = malloc(0);
array[0] = malloc(0);
strcpy(array[0],"hello");
array[1] = malloc(0);
strcpy(array[1],"world");
```

What the hell is going on? When I replace any of the mallocs with NULL or remove them 
it doesn't work but it doesn't seem to matter what value is inside malloc granted it's 
not negative.

Comment: Undefined behaviour can work if it wants to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help other visitors to Stack Overflow in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing an invalid pointer is an undefined behavior; so anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc(0)` is implementation-defined and returns either a null pointer or an invalid pointer.

You are invoking undefined behavior by using the pointer returned by `malloc(0)`.

Comment: but the same thing happens for malloc(1)

Comment: @CadellChristo it is also undefined behavior with `malloc(1)` but for another reason: you are writing past the elements of the array object.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the undefined behaviour of `malloc(0)`. Malloc implementations often have a minimal granularity for the allocated blocks for alignment reasons. Which means that any block will always have at least a size of 4, 8, 12, 16 bytes, depending on implementation. If I remembered correctly, you can even set this value with a `mallopt` call on certain platforms.

The other thing is, that buffer overflows in allocation code often only crashes when you try to free the pointer(s), because only then is the memory around your block used for internal book keeping used by the library. That's one of the reasons why buffer overflows are so difficult to catch, they manifest at different locations and times then when they occured.